# Textview does not change with changing selection in android 3d carousel

Tags: android, carousel, textview

I am trying to use Android 3D Carousel (codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel) in my android app. In the demo, there is a textview at the top of the activity in which the text changes as the selection in the 3D carousel changes. This is the xml for the main.xml that is used in the activity.

```
  <com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel
        android:id="@+id/carousel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:animationDuration="200"
        pj:Items="@array/entries"
        pj:Names="@array/names"
        pj:SelectedItem="0"
        pj:UseReflection="true" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selected_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:background="#1E1921"
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textStyle="normal" />
```

The arrays "@array/entries" and "@array/names" both contain 6 items each. The problem is that when i try to increase the no. of items in these arrays, the TextView (selected_item) in the activity which has changing data with the selection of an item in carousel stops changing. It just displays The first item. Below is the code for TextView :-

```
 carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

            switch(position){
            case 0:
                txt.setText("The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felids and felines, is a small, usually furry, domesticated, carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and for its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. Cats have been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years, and are currently the most popular pet in the world. Owing to their close association with humans, cats are now found almost everywhere in the world.");
                break;
            case 1:
                txt.setText("The hippopotamus (Hippopotamus amphibius), or hippo, from the ancient Greek for \"river horse\" (ἱπποπόταμος), is a large, mostly herbivorous mammal in sub-Saharan Africa, and one of only two extant species in the family Hippopotamidae (the other is the Pygmy Hippopotamus.) After the elephant, the hippopotamus is the third largest land mammal and the heaviest extant artiodactyl.");
                break;
            case 2:
                txt.setText("A monkey is a primate, either an Old World monkey or a New World monkey. There are about 260 known living species of monkey. Many are arboreal, although there are species that live primarily on the ground, such as baboons. Monkeys are generally considered to be intelligent. Unlike apes, monkeys usually have tails. Tailless monkeys may be called \"apes\", incorrectly according to modern usage; thus the tailless Barbary macaque is called the \"Barbary ape\".");
                break;
            case 3:
                txt.setText("A mouse (plural: mice) is a small mammal belonging to the order of rodents. The best known mouse species is the common house mouse (Mus musculus). It is also a popular pet. In some places, certain kinds of field mice are also common. This rodent is eaten by large birds such as hawks and eagles. They are known to invade homes for food and occasionally shelter.");
                break;
            case 4:
                txt.setText("The giant panda, or panda (Ailuropoda melanoleuca, literally meaning \"black and white cat-foot\") is a bear native to central-western and south western China.[4] It is easily recognized by its large, distinctive black patches around the eyes, over the ears, and across its round body. Though it belongs to the order Carnivora, the panda's diet is 99% bamboo.");
                break;
            case 5:
                txt.setText("Rabbits (or, colloquially, bunnies) are small mammals in the family Leporidae of the order Lagomorpha, found in several parts of the world. There are eight different genera in the family classified as rabbits, including the European rabbit (Oryctolagus cuniculus), cottontail rabbits (genus Sylvilagus; 13 species), and the Amami rabbit (Pentalagus furnessi, an endangered species on Amami Ōshima, Japan)");
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
        }

    }
    );
```

And the xml for the entries and names arrays :-

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<array name="entries">
    <item>@drawable/cat</item>      
    <item>@drawable/hippo</item>        
    <item>@drawable/monkey</item>       
    <item>@drawable/mouse</item>
    <item>@drawable/panda</item>        
    <item>@drawable/rabbit</item>                       
</array>    
<array name="names">
    <item>The cat</item>
    <item>The hippo</item>
    <item>The monkey</item>
    <item>The mouse</item>
    <item>The panda</item>
    <item>The rabbit</item>
</array>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution here :-

In Carousel.java :-

change "if (angle != 0.0f)" to "if (Math.abs(angle) > 4)"

http://code.google.com/p/android-carousel-demo/issues/detail?id=1

Comment: Hello, swati can we change selection images in center visible in animation ?if you have any idea then send me please.

Comment: Hi.. I cant seem to understand what exactly are you asking. Do you want to change the images of the carousel?

Comment: How i can decrease speed of animation while i am touch with figure ?